# SQL string comparison: not equal but SQL says equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure named `sp_isSessionActive` that takes a parameter named 'token' containing the following SQL:

```
SELECT 1 AS Active 
FROM dbo.Mobile_Session
WHERE Token = @token AND GETDATE() BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime;
```

If I invoke that procedure with a token that exists in the database and is in the correct timespan, I get the correct result, 1.

```
EXEC sp_issessionactive @token='E883735B40CF4F939EAD133992770C87'
```

But if I add anything at the end of the token(which of course doesn't exist in the table), I also get 1!

```
exec sp_issessionactive @token='E883735B40CF4F939EAD133992770C87aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

What's going on? There's something I'm missing in the way SQL Server handles string comparisons..

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I don't see how what you describe is possible.   Can you set up a fully reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show us the stored procedure code!

Most importantly - how are the *parameters* of the stored procedure defined?

What's the *datatype* for your parameter `@Token`?

Is it just `VARCHAR` by any chance?

In that case - you've defined a parameter of *1 character length* - so of course it cannot distinguish those two strings you pass .....

Comment: Oooops, the @token parameter is of type char(32). That explains everything..!